# Why cannot I edit MOSFETs in LTspice by "nmos"

Tags: transistors, mosfet, ltspice

update: I edited question so that it will be mainly related to LTspice

[image]

OK, now I have used irfz44n for an example model, I realized that, by using the directive above(nmos), I am not able to modify Vto value. However if I use the second one(vdmos), I can control the Vto value. But while choosing the mosfet from component selector, I get it from "nmos" option. I wonder why this is the situation? Should I use `vdmos` instead of `nmos` all the time?

Comment: Knowing nothing about the model, that could be perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @MattYoung the model is ltspice default mosfet model, I am changing only the vto value.

Comment: You miss almost everything. People are not going to consult spice or guess the version or ... . Look at specs for a real world device or full specs for the LTS one, calculate what you'd expect and then comment if you find that your calculations are correct and SPICE's are wrong.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon please see my edit.

Comment: IRFZ44N datasheet [here](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfz44npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563b3a9f220d) At Vgs = 5V based on the datasheet I'd expects RDSon to be under 0.1 Ohm (probably worst case), so VDS a few mV.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon actually what I am trying to do is being able to modify parameters of a mosfet in ltspice. So I want to make that mosfet act as its vto is 1 V for example.

Comment: @muyustan vto = ???. | Maybe = Vgs(th) ?

Comment: @russellmcmahon yes threshold voltage, it is referred as vto in ltspice.

Comment: @muyustan Can and do you also specify the current at which Vgs(th) is specified, which is significant, and the subsequent absolute and change of channel resistance with increasing Vgs, which varies very greatly amongst devices. Presumably, using the models for real world device gives an approximation to a real real world result that can be compared to what you really get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the **vdmos** model IRFZ44N already exists in the component databases.

[image]

Adding a `.model IRFZ44N nmos(..)` card will not change the type of the IRFZ44N to a monolithic mosfet.
You are therefore not able to manipulate the parameters of the IRFZ44N using `.model nmos(..)`, but you can change them using `.model vdmos(..)`

Comment: I have to say that probably this is not correct too, because I can edit the behaviour of an npn for example 2n2222. And also I can edit irfz44n by .model irfz44n vdmos(.....).

Comment: @muyustan You're right again. With your comment, it is not hard the draw the conclusion in the updated answer.

Comment: I don't get what you are meaning by updated answer.

Comment: @muyustan Next time, I'll update before commenting :)

Comment: hahahah, thanks. I have quickly looked to all mosfet definitions which are premade in ltspice. They were all defined with vdmos. Are all those really vdmos? For example when I look datasheet of irfz44n it does not mention something as vdmos.